# How to dynamically load (and use) .net library with properly established dependencies using library versions?

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, dll, type-conversion

**Situation overview.**

We have several projects used in multifunctional system.

1. **objectAccessLibrary.dll** (multiple versions)
2. **dispatcherHandler.dll** (v.1.0) (dependency: 
   version independent part of **objectAccessLibrary.dll**)
3. Event handlers: **handler_01.dll**, **handler_02.dll**, **handler_03.dll**. 
   Dependencies: **dispatcherHandler.dll** (v.1.0), objectAccessLibrary.dll (particular
   version for each **handler_xx.dll**)
4. **DispatcherService** (dependency: particular version of **objectAccessLibrary.dll**). Dynamically loads handlers and using its functionality in order to dispatch events.

**The problem**

**objectAccessLibrary.dll** is under development along with core system. It is exposed some interfaces / objects which can be changed from version to version. Therefore **dispatcherHandler.dll** and **DispatcherService** should be recompiled and retested with old handlers each time we need to add new handler because it MUST use the newest version of **objectAccessLibrary.dll**.
But from other side **DispatcherService** MUST be running while **hanlder_xx.dll**'s are dynamically loaded.

The current version working fine if new handlers not using new **objectAccessLibrary.dll** features.
In general case we need to load different versions of **objectAccessLibrary.dll** and share some objects between them and **dispatcherHandler.dll**. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend looking into some kind of IoC container such as [StructureMap](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/index.html) or [Castle Windsor](http://www.castleproject.org/container/gettingstarted/index.html).  Both are pretty mature and will allow you to dynamically load dependencies into your projects.  There are many other containers out there as well that may also suit your requirements.

Comment: I have tried but other versions of assemblies are not loading when AppDomain has version loaded with dispatcherHandler.dll

Comment: Did you try specifically adding the versioned assemblies to the container?  I've specified the assembly names in a config file in the past and added them to the container that way.